# $\frac{(2n)!}{(n-p)!\cdot n!}\in\mathbb{N}$...?

Tags: calculus

> I would like to prove $\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n-p)!\cdot n!}\in\mathbb{N}\quad $ with $p\in [\![0,n-1]\!]$ from $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=C^k_n$

My intuition tell me if I build two sets such that :

$I:=\bigg\{x,\quad n\in \mathbb{N}^*,p\in [\![0,n-1]\!], x=\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n-p)!\cdot n!} \bigg\}$

and

$S:=\bigg\{x,\quad n\in \mathbb{N},k\in [\![0,n]\!],x=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\bigg\}$

then $I\subset S\subset\mathbb{N}$ but how to prove that???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $p \geq 0$ you can write
$$
\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n-p)!\cdot n!} = (2n)(2n-1)\cdots(2n-p+1)\dfrac{(2n-p)!}{(n-p)!\cdot n!}\\ = (2n)(2n-1)\cdots(2n-p+1)\tbinom{2n-p}{n} 
$$
Then all factors in the final expression are $\in \mathbb{N}$ (since also the binomial is $\in \mathbb{N}$), so the total expression is $\in \mathbb{N}$.

[If $p=0$ then there are no prefactors in front of the binomial.]

Comment: lovely thanks so mush